# Adding a reference to an ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to use the following system reference: [System.Device.Location.CivicAddress()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.civicaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on my ASP.NET MVC project, but nothing happens when I add it to the *using* section.

Here is my code snippet:

```
using System;
**using System.Device.Location;**
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Frappuccino.Models
{
    public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        public Int16 ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        **public CivicAddress Address { get; set; }**        
    }
 }
```

Someone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Visual Studio:

- In your project, you will have a references "folder". Right click that and click "add reference..".
- Alternatively, right click your project, go to add, and click "reference..".

This will add the assembly to your project.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)